# How to get proper error in catch statement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http, fetch

I use [ky.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky) for work with HTTP.

This is an example of how I handle the request:

[image]

And here I have a question, in the `catch` statement I expect that I will get the error object from Backend, but I get this error:

```
HTTPError
    at _callee$ (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/ky/index.js:367:23)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:17)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:282:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:116:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:5:24)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:27:9)
```

I suppose this is a webpack issue, but I don't know how to solve it. I'm using `TypeScript`, this is my `tsconfig` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "types"]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error object is a client side error created by ky.js.
If the backend creates an error and prints it to response body, you need to read the response body in order to get the error message. I don't know ky.js but I thing it is:

```js
error.response.text.then(text => console.log(text));
```

Comment: Did the console.log, and get response like this:

`ReadableStream {locked: false}`

Comment: Because the response body is not a string, but a ReadableStream. You need to read this stream to get the result (imagine a 10GB response, which can't even fit to memory) 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: Works, like that:

api
      .post('contract', { json })
      .then(() => closeAllocationModal())
      .catch(async err => {
        const { message } = await err.response.json();

        setAllocationError(message);
      });

Comment: Thx for your help!